# Query parsing in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am passing a query parameter which is look like this

```
var str="["56557e9e8091afc81a4371c8","565ac01b076fd1141492b594","565ab985076fd1141492b586","565aba0a076fd1141492b58c","565ab9d3076fd1141492b588","565aba4b076fd1141492b58e"]";
```

and it is being received into my node api which is look like this

```
console.log(req.query.pageModalIds);
```

now I want parse my query like this

```
return RuleSetModel.find({ 'pageId': { $in: req.query.pageModalIds } }, function (err, ruleset) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('get rule set');
            return res.send(ruleset);
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            console.log('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
            return res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
        }
    });
```

This method does not provide my data. what is my fault. Thanks.

N.B This is working If i set as fixed parameter which is below..

```
return RuleSetModel.find({ 'pageId': { $in: ["565a9fddf84313fc08b260dc","565ac01b076fd1141492b594"] } }, function (err, ruleset) {
```

Comment: is pageId ObjectId or simple strings in DB?

Comment: @SarathNair, if i set fixed like this { 'pageId': { $in: ["565a9fddf84313fc08b260dc","565ac01b076fd1141492b594"] } }, this is working.

Comment: One more clarification, Is req.query.pageModalIds String or Array Object?

Comment: I have posted an answer, please try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies with `req.query.pageModalIds`. Since you are not doing any processing to that it likely stays as a String Object. You need to convert it into array object before applying to query.A sample is shown below,

```
var pageModalIds = JSON.parse(req.query.pageModalIds)
```

After this you can apply $in query on this new variable. Try this and let me know. :)